# C prints random numbers on screen

Tags: arrays, c, printf

first of all pardon my english. I'm new to programming and C, wanted to make a program that given a base and exponent (which are asked to the user), it prints the answer... Problem is, sometimes it doesn't work... If I do for example "3" and "2", it gives "9" which is fine 3^2 = 9... But if I do 22^22 it prints: -2147483648... or for example if I do: 22222222 it doesn't ask me exponent and just prints -2147483648... I don't know why, it's because of the array max size? is because fgets max size? the printf type? something else?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int ask_base(){
  char num1[5];
  puts("Insert base:");
  fgets(num1, 5, stdin);
  int base = atoi(num1);

  return base;
}

int ask_exponent(){
  char num2[5];
  puts("Insert exponente:");
  fgets(num2, 5, stdin);
  int exponente= atoi(num2);

  return exponente;
}

int elevar_base(int base, int exponente) {
  int resultado = pow(base, exponente);
  return resultado;

}

int main(){
  printf("%d", elevar_base(pedir_base(), pedir_exponente()));
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: C doesn't have builtin arbitrary precision arithmetic. You must either implement it yourself or use some external library (for example, `gmp`). Integers in `C` are fixed width.

Comment: `-2147483648` is the minimum value for type `int` (presuming that type `int` on your machine uses 4 bytes)

Comment: Check the hexadecimal presentation of the magic number.  And check  https://linux.die.net/man/3/pow for the meaning of a negative number as return value.

Comment: The first chapter of any C book will mention numerical limits of the various integer types. Start with those chapters.

Comment: `22^22` is `341427877364219557396646723584` which is rather larger than a 32-bit `int` (or even 64-bit) can contain. Doesn't the compiler warn you about this with `int resultado = pow(base, exponente);`? Please don't ignore compiler warnings.

Comment: Talking about your secondary issue, the reason why _" if I do: 22222222 it doesn't ask me exponent and just prints -2147483648"_ is that you limited the base to four characters with `fgets(num1, 5, stdin);` (you declare a size of 5, meaning that at most your string will contain 4 digits and the terminator character).

Comment: ...and the next `2222` of the entry was taken for the second input. The system does not throw unused input away, and there is *still* the unread newline in the input buffer.